# How to drop SQL UNIQUE constraint without knowing its name?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL database .

I have created a Table as  shown below

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
UNIQUE (P_Id)
)
```

**Now i am trying to remove the Unique Constarint on the Persons table**

I have tried as

Comment: It`ll be called P_Id normally, otherwise do SHOW CREATE TABLE which should show you the name.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the tip show create table .